# Plot more than one CDF in single plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I created a function that computes `CDF` of my dataframe column. It returns a new dataframe with `column` passed, `frequency`, computed `PDF`, and  `CDF` like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def compute_distrib(df, col):
    stats_df = df.groupby(col)[col].agg('count').pipe(pd.DataFrame).rename(columns = {col: 'frequency'})
    
    # PDF
    stats_df['pdf'] = stats_df['frequency'] / sum(stats_df['frequency'])
    
    # CDF
    stats_df['cdf'] = stats_df['pdf'].cumsum()
    stats_df = stats_df.reset_index()
    return stats_df
```

So taking the following dataframe as example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

To compute the `CDF`, I do:

```
df_n = compute_distrib(df, 'B')
df_n.head()
      B     frequency   pdf     cdf
0   -2.124058   1      0.01     0.01
1   -1.949440   1      0.01     0.02
2   -1.738689   1      0.01     0.03
3   -1.733489   1      0.01     0.04
4   -1.693070   1      0.01     0.05
```

Then to plot the `CDF`:

```
df_n.plot(x='B', y=['cdf'], grid=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

But this function allows me to plot the  `CDF` of 1 column only from  the original `df`. How to I plot the `CDF` of columns `A,B,C,D` in one single plot?

Comment: You don't really need `plt.show()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'm not providing a pandas only solution. I think it will be easier to use [plotly](https://plotly.com/) or [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/). I'm going to slightly modify your `compute_distrib` as I don't think it's better to avoid having x with column names.

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4), columns=list('ABCD'))

def compute_distrib(df, col):
    stats_df = df.groupby(col)[col].agg('count')\
                 .pipe(pd.DataFrame).rename(columns={col: 'frequency'})
    
    # PDF
    stats_df['pdf'] = stats_df['frequency'] / sum(stats_df['frequency'])
    
    # CDF
    stats_df['cdf'] = stats_df['pdf'].cumsum()
    
    # modifications
    stats_df = stats_df.reset_index()\
                       .rename(columns={col:"x"})
    stats_df["col"] = col
    return stats_df

# I calculate cdf for every columns
cdf = []
for col in list('ABCD'):
    cdf.append(compute_distrib(df, col))
cdf = pd.concat(cdf, ignore_index=True)
```

## `plotly.express`

```py
import plotly.express as px

px.line(cdf, x="x", y="cdf", color="col")
```

[image]

## `seaborn`

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.lineplot(x=cdf["x"],
             y=cdf["cdf"],
             hue=cdf["col"]);
```

[image]

## Extra examples

I'm not sure if this is the case but there is a way to just plot the `cdf` without calculate it previously.

### `seaborn`

```py
import seaborn as sns

df1 = pd.melt(df, var_name="col", value_name="x")

kwargs = {'cumulative': True}
for grp in df1.groupby("col"):
    label = grp[0]
    grp = grp[1]
    kwargs["label"] = label
    sns.distplot(grp["x"], hist=False, kde_kws=kwargs)
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, you make my day.

Comment: I just added an example.

Comment: Interesting, so no need to write custom function.

Comment: Yes. I suggest you to explore `seaborn`. It provides many built-in solutions.

Comment: The extra example you added generates this error: `NameError: name 'kwargs' is not defined`.

Comment: My bad. It's fixed now.